# Do we need have a license for using Google NOTO fonts in Acrobat Reader?

Tags: font

I just came across a [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.lowagie/itext/2.1.0/com/lowagie/text/pdf/fonts/cmap_info.txt) which talks about the licensing part for using the Adobe fonts in Acrobat Reader PDF:

> "Note: The font software contained in this package is being licensed
>   to you solely for use with Adobe (R) Acrobat (R) Reader (R) software
>   ("Acrobat Reader") and is subject to the terms and conditions of the
>   electronic End-User License Agreement accompanying Acrobat Reader."
>
> This explains why iText doesn't ever embed a CJK font in the PDF file.
>   These fonts have to be downloaded and used in the context of Adobe
>   Reader; you can not use them with iText to produce a PDF document that
>   has these fonts embedded (as you would do with other fonts) so that
>   they can be viewed in other readers; unless you have a license from
>   Adobe to use these fonts.

I understood we can't use the Adobe fonts in Acrobat Reader without license, but how about using the Google NOTO fonts in Acrobat Reader? Do we need the license for this?

Comment: @unor I have corrected it :) you can review it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need a license to use Google NOTO fonts (unless you are the creator of those fonts), but that license is automatically given to you when you download the fonts.

The Google NOTO fonts are licensed under the [SIL Open Font License](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=OFL_web), which is an open-source font license that allows you to use and embed the font.

Comment: thanks for the answer.After getting the license from google NOTO can I use those fonts in IText ?? Does Adobe says anything about it ??

Comment: 1. You don't have to do anything to get a license for Google NOTO. You get the license automatically when you download the font package. 2. To my knowledge, Adobe doesn't have the legal right to forbid you to use other fonts. Their only option would be to make it technically difficult, which in turn makes their product less competitive. I don't know how easy it is to use iText with non-Adobe fonts and/or to embed those fonts.

Comment: Awesome let me reconfirm this from other sources, BTW there is an update in question please have a look thanks a lot BART for the info :) and BTW its easy to use NOTO fonts in IText.